# Is it OK to have a development branch where individual commits may not even be working?

Tags: git

For instance, I have two branches: `master` and `dev-personal`. Master always contains working stable releases, while `dev-personal` is used to sync code between several of my machines without any testing until it's time to merge, then my latest commit to `dev-personal` is tested and reviewed before the merge. Is it normal practice?

Comment: [Related](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119784/is-it-good-idea-to-require-to-commit-only-working-code)

Comment: Also [related](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211608/is-it-ever-ok-to-commit-non-working-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an standard practice.

In git it's a very good feature that we can create multiple branch and use them to share our progress with team mates.

For example:

**master branch:**
This branch supposed to contain stable and releasable code.

**Local branches:**
local branches are used to track individual's progress.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the minimum requirement before you push something to any branch is to check you don't break the compilation process. Related with branches, development branch is usually considered as a non-stable branch, meanwhile master branch is considered the stable branch, so some testing has to be done before merging develop to master.

Comment: My personal branches are not meant for anyone but me to use, so I just hit commit whenever I am done developing certain block of features for now, but may need to continue from another device.